# Shorthand for specifying path as pwd in Unix?

Tags: unix

I'd like to know if there's a built in shortcut or a way to create an alias for the path in a command when the path is the pwd. For example, lets say my pwd is ~/Desktop/Unix_Folder/Unix_Sub_Folder and I wanted do something like ...

```
find ~/Desktop/Unix_Folder/Unix_Sub_Folder -name '*txt'.
```

I'm thinking there must be a more efficient way to reference the pwd without typing it out, but I don't know what it is. Maybe there isn't, but it would be nice to know.  
Thanks,  
~Benny

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about simply:

```
find . -name '*txt'
```

(I hope I haven't misunderstood the question.)

Comment: Thanks, that's pretty much what I was looking for (I think I need to go back over my notes for the basics and see why that's not there;). Specifically, I'd like to know how to restrict the depth of the search to the pwd (not sub folders within the directory if there are any).  <br/>

Comment: On a separate note: If someone could tell me how to work with the mini-Markdown format with replies, so I don't keep making a turkey out of myself with random tags and unfinished responses I'd appreciate it! =]

Answer (score 0):

Using this command also we can do :

```
find `pwd` -iname "*.txt" -print
```

pwd - will print the current directory